# Why are environment variables being passed to sudo session and is it a concern?

Tags: security, environment-variables, sudo

I came across some readings about how allowing environment variables to be passed to root when sudoing is a security concern. This led me to check my environment to make sure I had the proper setup.

I am on Ubuntu and have the default sudoers file which includes:

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
...
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

From what I have read, it seems that the `env_reset` should strip out environment variables from the sudo session (unless overrode with env_keep or SETENV), but that does not seem to be happening.

```sh
$ sudo -u root echo $TERM
xterm-256color
$ export TERM=BLAH
$ sudo -u root echo $TERM
BLAH
```

This occurs with every environment variable I have tried. Is this a security concern? If so, how would I alleviate it? If not, why not (I was given to understand that someone could use this to tweak `PATH` to run malicious code as root)?

I do not have any files in my `sudoers.d` directory.

Edit:

It seems that the shell was expanding the variables before switching users in the example above. However, when I start an interactive shell, I get the same thing:

```sh
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
$ export TERM=BLAH
$ sudo -i         
# echo $TERM
BLAH
```

When I run the above snippet with `HOME` or `PATH`, however, *those* variables *are* reset, which matches what I expect from the [documentation](https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/1.8.13/sudoers.man/).

> The new environment contains the TERM, PATH, HOME, MAIL, SHELL, LOGNAME, USER, USERNAME and SUDO_* variables in addition to variables from the invoking process permitted by the env_check and env_keep options.

However, `TERM` is in that list, and you can see I was able to pass it to root, and it seems this works for other arbitrary variables as well.

Comment: Those variables listed in the *sudoers* documentation that you quote get a special treatment. I believe that TERM is actually preserved from the caller's environment. What is a bit surprising, and can't replicate on my end, is the preservation of other arbitrary variables as well. What result do you get if you run the following? ```export TEST=blah; sudo -i sh -c 'echo $TEST'```

Answer (score 0):

The interpretation of `$TERM` is being done by the parent shell, before `sudo` is even run, as you could see by prefacing your command with `echo`:

```
echo sudo echo $TERM
```

You could "escape" the `$` with `\` to delay interpretation one level:

```
sudo echo \$TERM
```

Read `man sudo sudoers bash`.

Comment: yes, as noted in my edit, I realized that, but even with switching to a sudo shell, the value of `TERM` persists. I have read through the sudoers man page, and in fact linked it in my edit, and this question exists because what i see doesn't seem to match what is described.

Comment: The `TERM` environment variable is used as a key into a database of terminal characteristics (cursor movement, character colors, magic "escape" sequences, ...). It doesn't change when one becomes `root` - it's the same terminal (terminal emulator). In the old days, when serial terminals each had their own set of magic characters, and magic behaviors, `TERM` was more useful. If one subverts `TERM`, all you get is a poorly configured glass keypunch. Try `TERM=something sudo echo \$TERM`.